How can a credit card company share information and enforce or offset debts?
So I do know of someone that owed the credit card section of a bank, $27,000, before the bank finally disconnected. Which brings me to several theoretical questions.

If someone owes the credit card of Bank A $27,000, do the other banks know about it? I heard that they do not know directly, but they can do through shared databases. But the database doesn't tell the bank an exact amount, just a range amount.

What if you owe Bank A $27,000, but you already have over $40,000 in Bank B. What can Bank A do in regards to that?

What if you owe the credit-card side of Bank A $27,000, but you do have $27,000 in the commercial-banking side of Bank A. Can Bank A seize that amount? And if so, do they send you a letter notifying you of that, in which you can just withdraw that money out, or can they seize it from you without notifying you, or do they have to take you to court for that, in which you would just withdraw that money out? Thanks.



Regarding 3: In the UK, I'm pretty certain I've seen clauses in Ts&Cs that would allow a bank to take funds from a savings account to pay off an overdrawn current/chequing account. Not noticed (but not explicitly looked) as to whether they can do something similar with a credit card.


If someone owes the credit card of Bank A $27,000, do the other banks
know about it? I heard that they do not know directly, but they can do
through shared databases. But the database doesn't tell the bank an
exact amount, just a range amount.

A credit report provides the exact amount (sometimes to the nearest dollar rather than the exact penny). Credit card issuing banks routinely  share this information with multiple credit reporting agencies. The exact circumstances when a bank can access your credit report are a bit complicated, but usually, it is able to do so. A couple of my credit card issuing banks review my credit report every month.

What if you owe Bank A $27,000, but you already have over $40,000 in
Bank B. What can Bank A do in regards to that?

Bank A can cease to let you borrow more if it thinks you can't repay it all. If you are in default with Bank A, Bank A can sue you, and if Bank A wins, it can force you to tell it when you have bank accounts, and garnish the bank account at Bank B (or you wages, or seize your property to the extent that it isn't exempt from creditors).

What if you owe the credit-card side of Bank A $27,000, but you do
have $27,000 in the commercial-banking side of Bank A. Can Bank A
seize that amount? And if so, do they send you a letter notifying you
of that, in which you can just withdraw that money out, or can they
seize it from you without notifying you, or do they have to take you
to court for that, in which you would just withdraw that money out?

If you are in default the Bank A can setoff your credit card debt against your bank deposit debt at Bank A. Bank A's right of setoff has priority over the claims of other creditors to the bank deposit funds in a bankruptcy.
You are typically notified immediately after the setoff is done, if you are in default. Of course, you should know whether you are in default or not, from your credit card statement and your payment history, and usually, the bank won't setoff unless you are seriously in default.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In order for a bank to know about your debt, they will have to run a "credit report", which an only be done with your permission.
If the bank that you owe sues you and wins in court they can have the court "garnish" your bank account and wage, perhaps even repossess or sieze your property. The specifics depend on the state and circumstances.

So when you owe Bank A $27,000, Bank A doesn't tell other banks about it? Even indirectly? I thought it could put some data down in a database, and through banks sharing the same database, can know something about it.

@NealConroy Bank A will likely report the debt to a credit reporting agency. These are companies that make it their business to keep such a database. However, the other banks can't just see whats in the database. They have to ask you for permission to ask the agency to tell them. The contents of which is what makes up a "credit report".

@user1937198 okay, so basically, the credit report agency absorbs the information but doesn't do anything with it. They can't give the info to other banks...
I'm wondering what if you owe Bank A $27,000, but you have $40,000 in Bank B, and then, Bank A and Bank B got merged into the same bank...

Is it really the default that they have to get your permission to view your credit report? I know you can lock your credit report to require this, but I didn't think it was locked by default.

Your permission is only needed for hard pulls, checks to establish credit. If you already have a relationship banks are doing soft pulls and no explicit permission for each pull is needed other than the existing service agreement

A bank doesn't have to go through a court process to set off your deposits with the bank agains debts owed to the same bank. Garnishment and court process are used when there isn't identity between the debtor and the creditor.

@Barmar Often, the right to pull reports occasionally is in the contracts to gain credit cards.

Okay @user1937198 and

@littleadv from what I gather, if you owe the credit card side of BankA $27,000, BankB will be alerted if you tried to open a credit card with them, but not if you try to open a savings/checkings of BankB?
